# Building a selenium framework using POM and need some advise from experts

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks

Building a selenium framework using POM and trying to add common action class for repeatedly used functions like set text, get text, set radiobutton, listbox etc., structure like below

Test --> POM page object

POM page object --> common action class

```
@Test
public void verifyGooglebuttontext() {
    System.out.println("set search value");
            googlepage.setSearchValue("Google Test");
    Assert.assertEquals(addC.verifytext(),"Google");
}
```

POM

```
@FindBy(name="q")
WebElement txtGoogleSearch;

public static setSearchValue(String txt) {
         setText(txtGoogleSearch, txt)
}
```

Common Action class

```
public void setText(WebElement element,String Value ){
        element.sendKeys(Value);
}
```

My query is whether this will impact in performance as I have to call 2 functions rather than setting and getting control values directly in Page object class.

Please advise.

Comment: why you need Common action class?

Comment: at times like selection of multiple dropdown list and selection of radio buttons or listbox I don't need to write same set of codes again and again on each Page object classes. To reduce redundancy of code.

Comment: When you say POM, I am assuming POM = Page Object Model and not the Maven POM. Clarity helps others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that most of the time you'll wait for the page loading and search for elements in the loaded page's DOM, I wouldn't worry too much about two extra function calls.

Really, page loading will take ages (> milliseconds) in comparison with a method call (microseconds or less).

What you gain from that is massively better: if the UI changes, you'll have to revisit a small number of places to adjust to the new element locations/type/ways to carry an action (while your @Test logic  can stay virtually unchanged). Which means you'll be up-and-running in hours rather than a couple of day to go all over your code and locate/change all places affected by a change in UI.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you aren't reducing redundancy, you are adding to it. You are taking a one liner `driver.findElement(...).sendKeys(value)` and changing it to a different one liner `setText(driver.findElement(...), value)` but creating an additional function `setText()`. There's no need to add another layer of complexity here. It doesn't save any time here or during maintenance.

```
@FindBy(name="q")
WebElement txtGoogleSearch;
public static setSearchValue(String txt) {
    txtGoogleSearch.sendKeys(txt);
}
```

I would not use `PageFactory`. If you test sites of any complexity, you will find yourself refetching elements on the page after the initial load. To avoid this, define your locators are part of the page object and use them to fetch elements when you need them.

Sample page object

```
public class AutomationPracticeTablePage
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private By pageTitleLocator = By.xpath("//h1[text()='Automation Practice Table' and @class='h1-size']");
    private By tableHeadingLocator = By.cssSelector("table > thead th");

    public AutomationPracticeTablePage(WebDriver webDriver) throws IllegalStateException
    {
        this.driver = webDriver;

        // wait for page to finish loading
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pageTitleLocator));

        // see if we're on the right page
        if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("/automation-practice-table/"))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the Automation Practice Table page. Current URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        }
    }

    public List<String> getHeadings()
    {
        List<String> headings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (WebElement heading : driver.findElements(tableHeadingLocator))
        {
            headings.add(heading.getText());
        }

        return headings;
    }
}
```

Sample code to use the page object

```
driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-table/");
AutomationPracticeTablePage automationPracticeTablePage = new AutomationPracticeTablePage(driver);
System.out.println(automationPracticeTablePage.getHeadings());
```

Comment: I could argue that having such a function as setText(element, text) is useful. But, not as implemented here. It can be useful if there is additional support within the new function. ie: input fields are being overwritten by javascript that changes the dom, well, we could add support to wait for the javascript by polling for classname, id etc.. to appear before trying to insert text. wait for input field to not be readonly...

In all this is a good answer

Comment: @robx Agreed. I'm not saying that some sort of "helper function" is never useful... but only if there's enough meat in it to justify its existence. I never understood writing a wrapper around a one liner but I've seen it several times on here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you start by not abbreviating Page Object Model as POM. POM is associated to Maven as a project dependency management file. Also to get your your questions in a more clear state. The more clear and concise you are, the better and quicker support you will get. You can visit http://toolsqa.com/ to get better understanding of Page Object Model structure, get creative, and make better your terminology.

This is a @Test script (method), not a class. It is also not a page object model. Any method annotated with this is considered a Test script to be executed.

```
@Test
public void verifyGooglebuttontext() {
    System.out.println("set search value");
            googlepage.setSearchValue("Google Test");
    Assert.assertEquals(addC.verifytext(),"Google");
}
```

This is a WebElement and a functional method within a page object. Not a Page Object Model

```
@FindBy(name="q")
WebElement txtGoogleSearch;

public static setSearchValue(String txt) {
         setText(txtGoogleSearch, txt)
}
```

This is not a class. It is a method in a class.

```
public void setText(WebElement element,String Value ){
        element.sendKeys(Value);
}
```

Okay, now, your setText(WebElement, String) method is too thin to provide any value as is. You can however, add additional support into the method if you find it necessary. Most of my experience doesn't require additional support for input fields, but I have ran across some that do need additional support when javascript is involved; DOM manipulation after page load.

The point and advise here, is that don't over complicate what isn't necessary. Work with what currently works, and tweak for support as you go. Now, if you can see further into the outlook of the project that you will be needing such support, go for it, and implement the support ahead of time.